# How to replace values for similar values by mean for all columns?

Tags: r

I have this data frame here

```
 df = structure(list(D = c(-76, -74, -72, -70, -44, -42), A = c(83, 
 83, 82, 82, 81, 81), B = c(-0.613, -0.4,-0.5, -0.68, -0.13, -0.26)), row.names = 
c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to compute the mean of all values in B that have similar value in A.

for instance -0.613 and -0.4 as they correspond to the same values 83 etc

I can simply do this :

```
   df$Bmean <- with(df, ave(B, A))
```

However this only for B. I need to do the same thing for all columns (B,D,etc.) in df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mutate` with `across` from `dplyr` for multiple columns

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
df %>% 
   group_by(A) %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), list(mean = ~ mean(.))))
```

If it is to replace original column with `mean`

```
df %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

NOTE: `na.rm = TRUE` is added in case there are any NA values as by default it is `na.rm = FALSE`

---

Or to have fine control over the column names

```
df1 <- df %>% 
         group_by(A) %>%
         mutate(across(everything(), list(mean = ~ mean(.)), .names = "{col}mean"))
df1
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   A [3]
#      D     A      B Dmean  Bmean
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1   -76    83 -0.613   -75 -0.506
#2   -74    83 -0.4     -75 -0.506
#3   -72    82 -0.5     -71 -0.59 
#4   -70    82 -0.68    -71 -0.59 
#5   -44    81 -0.13    -43 -0.195
#6   -42    81 -0.26    -43 -0.195
```

---

Or using `ave` for multiple columns, get the vector of column names that are not the grouping ("A" with `setdiff` ('nm1'),  Loop over the vector, subset the dataset column, use that in `ave` and assign it back to the dataset as new columns with `paste`

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(df), "A")
df[paste0(nm1, "mean")] <- lapply(nm1, function(nm)  ave(df[[nm]], df$A))
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to replace the original columns by the new ones (mean)

Comment: @Tpellirn  If it is toreplace original, just do `df %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate(across(everything(), mean))`

Comment: @Tpellirn I used `dplyr 1.0.0` `across` is from that version

Comment: @Tpellirn if your dplyr version is less than 1.0.0, then the answer in the other post should work for you.  In the future, those functions with suffix `_at/_all` etc will be deprecated though

Answer (score 1):

You could use this approach

```
library(dplyr)
#Approach 1
df %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate_all(mean,na.rm=T)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   A [3]
      D     A      B
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1   -75    83 -0.506
2   -75    83 -0.506
3   -71    82 -0.59 
4   -71    82 -0.59 
5   -43    81 -0.195
6   -43    81 -0.195

#Approach 2
df %>% group_by(A) %>% summarise_all(mean,na.rm=T)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
      A     D      B
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1    81   -43 -0.195
2    82   -71 -0.59 
3    83   -75 -0.506
```